# Trying to get the sum of php array object in a nested loop

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.3

I know this is quite basic.

I'm trying to get the sum of qty for each of the keys from the below object but it doesn't return what I expect.

```
{
        "3": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "qty": 4,
                "customer_id": 3,
                "cargo_id": 3,
                "customer": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "company_name": "Mertz and Sons",
                    "phone": "(586) 898-5987"
                },
                
            }
        ],
        "6": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "qty": 9,
                "customer_id": 6,
                "cargo_id": 3,
                "customer": {
                    "id": 6,
                    "company_name": "Turcotte PLC",
                    "phone": "+13422302445"
                },
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "qty": 3,
                "customer_id": 6,
                "customer": {
                    "id": 6,
                    "company_name": "Turcotte PLC",
                    "phone": "+13422302445"
                },
                
            }
        ]
    }
```

Here is what I'm currently doing

```
$attrs = [];
foreach($record as $item=> $value){

            foreach($value as $k){
                $attrs['customer'] = $k['customer']['company_name'];
                $sum_ordered = 0;
                $sum_ordered += $k['qty']; 
                $attrs['ordered_sum'] = $sum_ordered;
            }
            $output[] = $attrs;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

and this is the result I get, I can't figure out what is not right. I'm expecting 4 and 12 respectively as `ordered_sum`

```
[
   {"customer":"Mertz and Sons","ordered_sum":4},
   {"customer":"Turcotte PLC","ordered_sum":3}
]
```

Comment: If that is a collection grouped by customer_id, I think something like this would do the job `$output = $record->map(function ($group) { return [ "customer" => $group->first()->customer->company_name, "ordered_sum" => $group->reduce(function ($carry, $item) { return $carry + $item->qty; }) ]; });`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

$record = '{
    "3": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "qty": 4,
            "customer_id": 3,
            "customer": {
                "id": 3,
                "company_name": "Mertz and Sons",
                "phone": "(586) 898-5987"
            }
        }
    ],
        "5": {
            "1": {
                "id": 2,
                "qty": 8,
                "customer_id": 5,
                "customer": {
                    "id": 5,
                    "company_name": "Reichert, Witting and Durgan",
                    "phone": "961.352.6817 x0265"
                }
            }
        },
        "6": {
            "2": {
                "id": 3,
                "qty": 9,
                "customer_id": 6,
                "customer": {
                    "id": 6,
                    "company_name": "Turcotte PLC",
                    "phone": "+13422302445"
                }
            },
            "3": {
                "id": 4,
                "qty": 3,
                "customer_id": 6,
                "customer": {
                    "id": 6,
                    "company_name": "Turcotte PLC",
                    "phone": "+13422302445"
                }
            }
        }
}';


$record = json_decode($record, true);

$output = [];
foreach($record as $item=> $value){
    $attrs = [
        'customer'    => '',
        'ordered_sum' => 0
    ];

    foreach($value as $k){
        $attrs['customer']     = $k['customer']['company_name'];
        $attrs['ordered_sum'] += $k['qty'];
    }

    $output[] = $attrs;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: it returns only one record

Comment: Is `$record` an array of arrays?

Comment: arrays please. If you check the data above, it has two keys.

Comment: Thank you so much. but I get this error `array_reduce() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given`

Comment: thank you, it returns only the last record

Comment: https://ideone.com/3nDy9q

Comment: @codervine your `$record` variable holds an invalid JSON string. I've formatted properly so now everything should work as expected. Kindly check out my updated answer.

Comment: remove the quotes that encloses $record . Thank you it's working

Comment: change `$record = '{}'` to `$record = {}`

Comment: That's odd. And it worked?

Comment: yes please, I did not have to decode again.

Comment: more like but without `collect()`.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Laravel

so you can utilize the collection function.

```
collect($array)
  ->flatten(1) // flatten the unnecessary array 
  ->groupBy(function($item) { // group by company name
       return $item['customer']['company_name'];
  })->map(function($items, $key) { // remap according to your needs
       return [
           'customer' => $key,
           'ordered_sum' => collect($items)->sum('qty'), // sum the qty
       ];
   })
   ->values() // remove keys
   ->toArray();
```

Output

```
=> [
 [
   "customer" => "Mertz and Sons",
   "ordered_sum" => 4,
 ],
 [
   "customer" => "Reichert, Witting and Durgan",
   "ordered_sum" => 8,
 ],
 [
   "customer" => "Turcotte PLC",
   "ordered_sum" => 12,
 ],
]
```